# How to solve application unable to start Error in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-7

IN MY laptop win 7  i have installed unity 2019.4.20. when i try to open  it shows the error .

the application was unable to start correctly(ox000007b).click ok to close the application.

i have replaced the necessary dll (32 bit to 64 bit). but the error is not solved.

kindly give solutions  how to solve this error.i have enclose the screenshot with this.
[image]

Comment: Did you try to reinstall unity?

Answer (score 1):

i updated my windws 7.Now its works fine and good.